# Are this is a bug in PHP language or what?

Tags: php

I really wondering about this code

```
<?    
  session_start()
 $_SESSION['me'] = 654;
    $me = $_GET['me'];

    echo  $_SESSION['me'];
?>
```

it will print the $me value not the $_SESSION['me'] value.

Are this is a bug or they do it for security reasons ? any Explanations ?

Comment: @wseem: it echoes 654 here, php5 , register globals: off

Comment: did you request the page and pass ?me=foo to it ?

Comment: Works here as well, echoes 654, PHP 5, register globals off, and with a differing GET parameter.

Comment: Any messages in the error log?

Comment: This code always outputs 654 even with register_globals enabled . . .

Comment: PHP5 register_globals = Off and echo the $_GET['me'] value - I run the code on the localserver->localhost . and still print the same result when I turn on the register_globals

Comment: @wseem Is this the entire script?

Comment: Is your code echo'ing the $_SESSION or $_GET 'me' variable?

Answer (score 5):

Do you have [**register_globals**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals) enabled by any chance?

**Edit:** This seems to have to do with the famous [**session side-effect that existed until PHP 4.3**](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=43722). If a session variable is not initialized, the value of a possibly existing global variable of the same name will be used.

> PHP versions 4.2.3 and lower have an undocumented feature/bug that allows you to initialize a session variable in the global scope, albeit register_globals  is disabled. PHP 4.3.0 and later will warn you, if this feature is used, and if  session.bug_compat_warn is also enabled. This feature/bug can be disabled by disabling this directive.

I still can't *quite* get my head around why exactly this happens, though. And what pygorex1 writes in his answer makes it even weirder.

Comment: Ok , i set register_globals = Off ,and the code work true and print the $_SESSION value , but when set register_globals = On , the code print the $me value , Why ?

Answer (score 3):

Are you calling `session_start()` anywhere?

If not, than php is probably second guessing what you mean so you can check the error log to see what is happening exactly.

Comment: sure , I called session_start();

Comment: Before any output is sent to the browser?

Answer (score 3):

I'm able to to recreate this behavior using PHP v5.2.10 with `register_globals` and after multiple visits to the page:

test.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['me'] = 654;
$me = $_GET['me'];
echo  $_SESSION['me'];
```

http://localhost/test.php?me=321

The first time the page is loaded the output is `654`. The second time the page is run the output becomes `321`. Why does this happen?

First Time:

- When first called the `$_SESSION['me']` variable doesn't exist, so it is NOT initialized as a global.
- `$_GET['me']` does exist and is initialized as global variable `$me`

Second Time:

- On page refresh the `$_SESSION['me']` variable now exists and is initialized as the global var `$me`
- `$me` now refers to `$_SESSION['me']`
- Any assignment to `$me` will overwrite the session variable, so the SESSION variable becomes `321` and the output becomes `321`

However, the OP states in a comment that he has register_globals turned off ... in that case I'm not sure what to make of it!